# Insert random values during EF migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How do I insert a random value, generated by the C# code during an code-first Entity Framework migration? I have added a column of serial numbers that has a unique index. The serial numbers are in the format XXXYYYY-X, where X is a number and Y is a alphabetical character. The serial numbers do not have to be in a sequence, they just have to be random (there is a small amount of records in the database, so the possibility of generating a duplicate serial number is small).

I have tried the following:

```
AddColumn("dbo.Product", "SrNo", c => c.String(maxLength: 9, fixedLength: true, unicode: false, defaultValue: RandomSerialNo()));
```

...but the migration creates just one serial number and tries to insert it for all records.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? I'm facing a very similar problem right now. I want to add an email column to a user table, and obviously want the column to be unique, but the migration fails because of duplicate values (either multiple nulls or the same random string).

Comment: Actually, not. I had to split the migration into two parts - first part changes the column. Then I manually run a script that ensures the data are unique. And then I add the unique constraint in a second migration.